# How does the gmail app handle push notifications in iOS?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to replicate gmail's handling of push notifications on iOS. There are two behaviours that I'm looking at:

1. When a new email is sent to my inbox, I receive a new notification with a corresponding increase in the badge number.
2. When I read/delete an email on the gmail website, the badge number decreases accordingly - although the notification isn't removed as it is on Android.

While the first is quite straightforward the second is what really confuses me, especially considering that this happens even after I kill the gmail app and/or restart the device.

From what I read/experimented with, when an app is not running it can only receive remote messages that must contain a display notification. These can be intercepted and modified by implementing a `UNNotificationServiceExtension` but eventually one **must** display the notification to the user or the system will take care of doing that.

So my question is what trickery does the gmail app use to receive messages when it is not running and how does it prevent these from ending up in the system tray?

Comment: They may make use of a silent notification. Once its received, they may do an API call to get the count of emails and update the badge. This is all just a maybe though as I don't know for sure how they do it. Head to the "Configuring a Silent Notification" section here to read more: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I am using FCM so the trick is to send a message payload containing a `notification` object. The `notification` object should only contain the `badge` value. This will cause the badge to be updated without displaying anything in the notification tray.

It is important to note however that this message cannot be intercepted/modified by the app (nor by a `UINotificationExtension`) so the following should be kept in mind:

1. One needs to keep track of the correct badge number server-side.
2. Passing data to this message may be futile as it'll be lost.
3. One cannot use this as a trigger to do anything in the app.
4. This is only really useful as a means to remove all the notifications for the app once the badge number hits 0.